# How do you code the likelihood of the normal distribution kernel in R manually?

Tags: r, statistics, log-likelihood

Specifically, how do you code the product of the differences of x and mu, precision matrix, and transpose of the differences of x and mu. Is my code below correct? Thanks in advance.

```
(colSums(dat-mu_mat)%*%solve(sigma)%*%colSums(dat-mu_mat))
```

where mu_mat is the row vector of means repeated down n times.

Full code is below:

```
dat<-rmvnorm(100,mean=c(200,0.1),sigma=matrix(c(5,0,0,0.02),nrow=2))
n<-nrow(dat)
mu<-matrix(c(200,0.1),nrow=1)
mu_mat<-matrix(rep(c(200,0.1),100),nrow=100,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)

loglik_mvn<-function(n,d,x,mu_mat,sigma){
  (-n*d/2)*log(2*pi)-(n/2)*det(sigma,log=TRUE)-0.5*(colSums(x-mu_mat)%*%solve(sigma)%*%colSums(x-mu_mat))

loglik_mvn(nrow(dat),ncol(dat),dat,mu_mat,sigma)
dmvnorm(dat,mean=mu,sigma=sigma,log=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the context for the question is. The kernel of a theoretical distribution is different than a likelihood and I do not see any term in that expression that is a kernel of a Normal distribution. Your expression does not create a transpose of the differences and you should post code that creates a sample dataset and  creates both a vector of means and a covariance matrix to support a full demonstration once you have clarified the purpose.

Comment: `sum(diag(solve(Sigma, tcrossprod(t(X)-MU))))` where `MU` is a vector of means. IT IS NOT A matrix

Comment: Thank you both. I edited my post to include the full code. Why doesn't my code work, out of curiosity? @onyambu can you please let me know what the format of your X and MU are? Is X nxd and Mu 1xd?

Comment: Check the code I provided below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have dataset and a vector of means, and the sigma, then you could compute the exponent part as:

```
sum(diag(solve(sig, tcrossprod(t(x) - mu))))
```

Therefore you likelihood will look like:

```r
log_like <- function(x, mu, sig){
  -sum(diag(solve(sig, tcrossprod(t(x) - mu))))/2 - #The part you are interested in
    nrow(x)*(ncol(x)*log(2*pi) + log(det(sig)))/2
}

x <- iris[-5]
mu <- colMeans(x)
sig <- var(x)

log_like(x, mu, sig)
#> [1] -379.9213

sum(mvtnorm::dmvnorm(x, mu, sig, TRUE)) # Produces same results as above
#> [1] -379.9213
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You could also use the following:

```
log_like2 <- function(x, mu, sig){
  u <- t(x) - mu #Notice mu is a vector and not a matrix
  -sum(u*solve(sig, u))/2 -  # the part you are interested in
   nrow(x)*(ncol(x)*log(2*pi) + log(det(sig)))/2
}

log_like2(x, mu, sig)
#> [1] -379.9213
```

putting all things together and using the recycling of R:

```
log_like3 <- function(x, mu, sig){
  u <- t(x) - mu
  -sum(u * solve(sig, u) + log(2*pi) + log(det(sig))/ncol(x))/2
}
log_like3(x, mu, sig)
[1] -379.9213
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is wonderful. I thought I was close with my own code, but nope haha.

Comment: @LifeisGood94 if this solves your problem, consider accepting the answer

Comment: I just did so. My apologies for you having to ask me to. I'm kind of new to this.

Comment: It doesn't really answer the question that I thought was being posed. (Maybe I'm wrong. My mind reading skills are a bit limited.) I assumed that the OP was trying to move from a mathematical expression such as one finds at the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution in the first formulation in that page's section entitled "Likelihood function" to an R expression that would accomplish the calculation. I might ask another question either here or on CrossValidated.com

Comment: @IRTFM OP was interested in coding the log likelihood of the multivariate normal as seen in the wikipedia page. OP wanted the solution to be the same as `sum(mvtnorm::dmvnorm(x, mu, sig, TRUE))` but without using the `dmvnorm` function. ie code by hand. Notice that this was OP's second attempt to ask the same question.

Comment: Thanks. I'll post another question to address what I obviously screwed up.

Comment: @IRTFM notice that the likelihood function on the wikipedia page is for a single observation. OP has many observations

Comment: Yes. I posted another question where I was able to calculate the sum of a set of N individual contributions to a log-likelihood using the expression I was looking at. But I thought there might be a compact matrix approach that more closely matched that expression, or I suppose filled in the gaps in my linear algebra knowledge that explains why `sum(u * solve(sig, u)` is the same as `sum{i=1,N} ( t(obs[n,]-mu) %*% S^-1 %*%  (obs[n,]-mu) )`.