# Implementing a particular approach to calculating a log-likelihood using matrix operations

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication, log-likelihood

I cam across a mathematical expression for log-likelihood in a [CrossValidated.com answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/351549/maximum-likelihood-estimators-multivariate-gaussian)  and am unclear how I should implement in R. I'm not sure if SO can represent MathML the same as CV, but this is the first equation in the second (not accepted) anser:

```
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
    \ell(\mu, \Sigma) &=& C - \frac{m}{2}\log|\Sigma|-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^m \text{tr}\left[(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (\mathbf{x}^{(i)}-\mu)\right]\\
$$
```

[image]

I focusing on the 3rd term in that equation and I do not think the trace operation is necessary according to another answer on that page. I suppose I could look at one of the several implementations in the various packages that exist, but I'm thinking they use more economical approaches that don't clearly follow that equation's procedure, as did @onyambu in the [answer here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75479505/how-do-you-code-the-likelihood-of-the-normal-distribution-kernel-in-r-manually)

I'm ripping out code from an earlier SO example:

```
library(MASS)
# Make covariance matrix. See note above re the implications of using a correlation matrix.
S = matrix(c(1.0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.35, 0.0,
0.2, 1.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0,
0.1, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.4,
0.35, 0.4, 0.0, 1.0, 0.6,
0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0), ncol = 5)
colnames(S) = c("Y1", "X1", "X2", "Z1" ,"Z2")
rownames(S) = colnames(S)
# Make mean vector
mus = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); names(mus) = colnames(S)
# Generate 5347 observations
obs = mvrnorm(n = 200, mu = mus, Sigma = S)
```

This effort was in response to a question correctly answered now but not using a summation of a matrix expression. I think I can do it with a  for-loop to create individual contributions for each data point:

```
llmat.term3 <- matrix(NA, 200,1)
for(n in 1:200) {
     llmat.term3[n] <- t(obs[n,]-mus) %*% solve(S) %*% (obs[n,]-mus) }
sum(llmat.term3)
#[1] 982.7356
```

.... but I'm wondering if there is a more compact matrix approach?  Or I suppose, filled in the gaps in my linear algebra knowledge that explains why `sum(u * solve(sig, u)` is the same as `sum{i=1,N} ( t(obs[n,]-mu) %*% S^-1 %*%  (obs[n,]-mu) )`.

Comment: This site does not accept latex. I dont like this hahaha. Anyway More compact way: `Tr[S(X-U)'(X-U)]` where S is the precision matrix. ie inverse of Sigma and X is a matrix of observations

Comment: in base R, I gave the equivalence to be `sum(diag(solve(cov(X), tcrossprod(t(X) - colMeans(X)))))`

Comment: Mathematically, If you use `trace`, you should remove `\sum_{i=1}^m` any more and replace `X^{i}` by `X`

Answer (score 1):

in your code you have

```
S = matrix(c(1.0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.35, 0.0,
             0.2, 1.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0,
             0.1, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.4,
             0.35, 0.4, 0.0, 1.0, 0.6,
             0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0), ncol = 5)
colnames(S) = c("Y1", "X1", "X2", "Z1" ,"Z2")
rownames(S) = colnames(S)
# Make mean vector
mus = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); names(mus) = colnames(S)
# Generate 5347 observations
set.seed(123)
obs = MASS::mvrnorm(n = 200, mu = mus, Sigma = S)
llmat.term3 <- matrix(NA, 200,1)
for(n in 1:200) {
  llmat.term3[n] <- t(obs[n,]-mus) %*% solve(S) %*% (obs[n,]-mus) }
sum(llmat.term3)
#[1] 982.7356
```

compare to more compact approaches:

```
u <- t(obs) - mus

sum(diag(solve(S, tcrossprod(u))))
#> [1] 982.7356    
sum(u * solve(S, u))
#> [1] 982.7356
```

Though the two expressions give similar results, The first one seems to be quicker than the second. I do not know why since in the first one there is a computation of n * n matrix.  The for loop takes for-ever to compute.

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq       mean    median        uq       max  neval
    a 4532.6753 4679.4043 5470.94765 4815.1294 6061.3284 7789.5116     10
    b    2.8991    3.2693    3.73495    3.3675    3.7777    6.9719     10
    c    7.8176    8.5473   12.03060    9.2542   16.4089   20.1742     10
```

---

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 200000

obs = MASS::mvrnorm(n = n, mu = mus, Sigma = S)
u <- t(obs) -mus

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(a = {
  llmat.term3 <- matrix(NA, n,1)
  for(i in seq(n)) {
   llmat.term3[i] <- t(obs[i,]-mus) %*% solve(S) %*% (obs[i,]-mus) }
  sum(llmat.term3)
  },
  b = sum(diag(solve(S, tcrossprod(u)))),
  c = sum(u * solve(S, u)),
  check = 'equal', times = 10)
```

NB: took me a while to get the seed you used. Next time include it in your data generation

Comment: Sorry. I guess you determined by experiment that it was 123. I know that LaTeX is not supported on SO, and now I need to learn how to convert to MathJax.

Comment: @IRTFM you asked for compact forms. Now for the algebra, this site does not accept latex hence difficulty for one to express themselves. The first one is straight forward as it uses the trace properties. The second is a bit tricky though you can check the algebra

Comment: @IRTFM yeah I dont know how to embed latex using Mathjax. Hopefully will one day